# CakePHP find by date range?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to fetch coupons that haven't expired yet. I have this in my controller:

```
public function coupons() {
    $this->paginate['Coupon']=array(
        'limit'=>9,
        'order'=>'RAND()',
        'conditions'=>array(
        'Coupon.end_date'=>??????)
    );
    $c=$this->paginate('Coupon');
    $this->set('allcoupons', $c);
}
```

I need it to return all records not expired as of today. `end_date` is in DATE format. I don't know how to ask cake to look at `end_date` and compare it to today, AND do it inside the paginate method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to format your date properly

```
'Coupon.end_date >' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Comment: So the greater than sign goes inside the single quotes?

Comment: Yep, for any kind of comparison operation in a CakePHP query the operator goes in the key. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to be using the [time helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper%3a%3adayAsSql) function dayAsSql in your controller so that you have something like

```
public function coupons() {
    $expire_interval = "3 days";
    $this->paginate['Coupon'] = array(
        ...
        'conditions' => 
            ## called via TimeHelper
            $this->Time->dayAsSql($this->Time->fromString($expire_interval), 'end_date')
        )
    );
    ....
}
```

Comment: The TimeHelper stuff has been moved to a Lib class in Utility for cleaner MVC access inside models etc. So your Answer is not quite correct.

Comment: That is true (and it's use is also shown when called as CakeTime from the model, from the provided link) but I based my answer to this question on the question asked. "...expired yet. I have this in my controller:" I wasn't trying to belittle someone on the internet, rather my goal was to help them solve their problem and provide something useful for others who may stumble across this question.

Comment: The probem was already solved one year ago (if you take a look at the timestamps). You just added wrong information to an outdated question here. You could at least use the proper class (CakeTime) here then. PS: You would also need to include it properly - using App::uses().